# Abstract Algebra: Prove Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a small problem with proving homomorphism with this function:
$f: \mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{R}^+$ defined by $f(a+bi) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

what I tried to set up $f( (a+bi) + (a'+b'i) ) = f(a+bi) + f(a'+b'i)$
then switch position: $f( (a+a') + (b + b')*i) = f(a+bi( + f(a' + b'i)$

substitute the function above: $\sqrt{(a + a')^2 + (b + b'^2)} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} + \sqrt{a'^2 + b'^2}$

square both side and start solving from that but it didn't end up equal.
Anyone saw what I did wrong with my proving?

Answer (score 5):

I think that perhaps you do not understand the group operation on $\mathbb C^{*}$; it's multiplication (of complex numbers) rather than addition. Change to that, and things should work out much better.

Comment: yes, it is one problem I thought about it but cant find what operation C* use . Thank you

Comment: @user2452885 $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ is not even closed under $+$, as witnessed by $1 + (-1) = 0$.

Comment: I just told you: it's multiplication of complex numbers, as in $(3 + 2i) * (4-i) = 12 + 8i - 3i - 2i^2 = 12 + 5i + 2 = 14 + 5i$.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been pointed out $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ is only a group under multiplication. However I'd like to throw my 2 cents in, remember a complex number can be written in 2 ways
$$a+bi=re^{i\omega}$$
where we have $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
and as such we can have 
$$f(a+bi)=f(re^{i\omega})=r$$
at which you can show it is a group homomorphism fairly easy as $(\mathbb{R}_+,\cdot)$ is the target group, also multiplicatoin.